# If Titan was suddenly raised to an earth-like temperature, how long before it melts?

Tags: moons, terraforming, time, temperature, water-bodies

After terraforming Mars, humans are now attempting to terraform Saturn’s moon Titan. Having removed much of its dense atmosphere, (reducing the pressure to just 0.7 bars) the colonists have now built a series of giant mirrors orbiting the moon to both focus sunlight onto the surface and reduce its day/night cycle from 16 days to 24 hours.

The result is that Titan now receives the same amount of sunlight as earth, and has the same day length.

Once these mirrors are in place, how long before Titan’s surface has warmed sufficiently for its famous methane lakes to evaporate, and its crust to thaw and form a global ocean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely convinced a single number can be given to you as different frozen materials unfreeze at different rates. But ice here on earth melts at the very rough rate of 2.5 cm per day and Titan's deepest ocean is thought to be 200 km thick. So simplistically maybe 2/3 of a year? But it'll get slower as the depth increases because the heat won't reach that far down. OK, from a practical perspective, probably 1-2 decades. And I'm very likely completely wrong.